# Copy parquet files from source to a destination sink, as files, maintaining folder hierarchy in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, parquet

I have telemetry data coming in from various devices every day via IOT. In Azure Data Factory, I roll these up into daily and then monthly parquet files. This works fine.

I want to introduce a new step to archive my 'daily' parquet files as they are rolled into monthly parquet files. I want to keep the source 'daily' parquet files as is, but ZIP'd up in my blob storage.

Attempting to use the COPY pipelines action in Azure Data Factory using the compression option on the destination dataset does not appear to do this.

1. Selecting 'parquet' as a data set file type only allows combining the parquet files into a single file.  I can only select 'merge' as an option - This isn't what I'm looking for.
2. Attempting to 'fool' Data Factory by selecting any other source/destination type doesn't work as it reads the source files and throws an error about compatibility.

Is what I'm looking to achieve possible? A simple archive of a set of source files into a compressed archive, maintaining the source structure?

**Example Source Structure**

```
trusteddata/<year>/<month>/<day>/some-file.parquet

trusteddata/2023/11/01/some-file.parquet
trusteddata/2023/11/02/some-file.parquet
trusteddata/2023/11/03/some-file.parquet
trusteddata/2023/11/04/some-file.parquet
...
trusteddata/2023/11/31/some-file.parquet
```

**Example Desired**

```
trusteddata/2023/11/myNovemberDailyFileArchive.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the parquet files using binary files in the copy activity source and sink.

Take a binary source dataset and give the path till the container in the dataset. Use the wild card path like below for the remaining path.

[image]

Give the target path in the binary target dataset. Give the `ZipDeflate` compression for it.

[image]

Make this dataset as sink for the copy activity and debug the pipeline. The target `.zip` file will be generated like below.

[image]

The above folders will be copied to the zip file.

[image]